# Vue-stash reactivity not working in data variables

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm using Vue-stash as an alternative to vuex. Vue-stash itself is reactive. However, if I use it inside a data variable, that variable isn't changing

```
<template>
 <div>
  {{id}} // not reactive
 </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      id: this.$store.id
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Vue instance's data property only gets set once on instantiation.

If you want the `id` to always reflect the value of `this.$store.id`, you should use a computed property:

```
export default {
  computed: {
    id() {
      return this.$store.id;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: OK. What if I use vuex instead of it?

Comment: Same deal. Nothing set in the `data` object is going to be reactive.

Comment: I'm only at about 75% on Vue, but I'm quite concerned that so far I've found the `data` property of any given component mostly useless so far.